# VSTO: "Can't find project or library" error occurs on Property Get CallVSTOAssembly

Tags: excel, vba, clickonce, vsto, customization

Using Visual Studio 2008
Excel 2007 workbook customization using VSTO

The error "Can't find project or library" recently began occurring in the Excel VBA editor on the following line of code:

```
   Property Get CallVSTOAssembly() As ShipdebitClaimProcessor.ThisWorkbook
```

This only happens on clients using the published version. On my development PC it works fine. On the client in the VBE, under Tools, References, it says

```
MISSING: ShipDebitClaimProcessor
Location: C:\MyCompany\OfficeApplication\Excel\ShipDebitClaimProcesor\bi
```

Although the location appears truncated, it probably points to the assembly located in the bin folder as it exists on my development PC. Of course, this path does not exist on the client. What should it say instead to make it work on the client, and how can it be corrected? Is it supposed to reference the ClickOnce cache somehow?

This customization has been in use for several years. It may have been broken by the most recent changes which involved deleting some sheets and changing the VBA code.  I've tried creating a new project from scratch, using an existing Excel file, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to

- Make the library available in client's desktop

OR

- Removing the reference from the project

First of all, you need to know why and when every reference is used within the project. I believe the best to do now is to remove the reference and retest your application, to ensure this library is no longer used (otherwise, clients would have problems without it in previous versions as well).

Rgds

Comment: This is a VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for office) application using ClickOnce, as described in Extend Your VBA Code With VSTO (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163373.aspx). Removing the reference results in the message "Compile error: User-defined type not defined", with the cursor on "Property Get CallVSTOAssembly()". That CallVSTOAssembly property was generated by VSTO when I set the EnableVbaCallers property in Visual Studio.  CallVSTOAssembly’s purpose is to connect VBA to my VSTO (.NET ) assembly ShipDebitClaimProcessor.dll, making it possible to call its .NET code from VBA.

Comment: The statement has been invoked for several years by other VBA code I wrote. When you set EnableVbaCallers to true in Visual Studio, Visual Studio automatically sets another property to true: ReferenceAssemblyFromVbaProject (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386306.aspx#PropertyTasks). That creates the reference that is visible under Tools, References.  At one point in my troubleshooting I thought I noticed a GUID in it, which could have been the value of the _AssemblyName property automatically created by VSTO (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds87aeyf%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I wonder if the GUID belongs there instead of the path to my bin folder, but I don’t know how to get VSTO to recreate the GUID. The Troubleshooting section on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386306.aspx , in the fourth table row, is somewhat close to the issue. “After you rename the customization assembly, VBA code that calls into the customization assembly stops working.” However, the solution it recommends didn’t work in my case.

Comment: I am getting a popup error message when I toggle the value of ReferenceAssemblyFromVbaProject: “"Property value is not valid" exception from HRESULT: 0x800A802D. I get no hits on search engines for these searches:
"Property value is not valid" ReferenceFromVbaAssembly
 “Property value is not valid”  EnableVbaCallers
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A802D

Comment: Six weeks ago I made changes to the application, and tested it locally. Finding no errors I published it. It was not put to use until a few days ago, when the error was noticed. In my initial troubleshooting on a test PC I found a transient error message in the event log:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.ControlNotFoundException: This document might not function as expected because the following control is missing: Sheet5.
Data that relies on this control will not be automatically displayed or updated, and    
other custom functionality will not be available.

Comment: I thought this might be because I had deleted an obsolete sheet from the workbook. This error no longer occurs, but the problem I am still experiencing feels like a configuration setting got corrupted somewhere.